# Add a multicast delegate that holds all four math procedures?

Tags: vb.net, delegates, invoke, multicast

I had to write the small vb.net console program shown below for my programming class. Now I have to do this:

> Add a multicast delegate that holds all four procedures. Call the procedures using the DynamicInvoke() method.

How would I do that? I tried everything I could think of but can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code. Feel free to do whatever you'd like to it. Any help and explanations are appreciated. Thanks!

```
Imports System
Module Module1
Dim a, b, result as Integer
Private Delegate Sub myDelegate()
Sub Main()
    Dim ask As myDelegate
    ask = New myDelegate(AddressOf Ask1)
    ask()
    Dim Multiply1 As myDelegate
    Multiply1 = New myDelegate(AddressOf Multiply)
    Multiply1()
    Dim Subtraction1 As myDelegate
    Subtraction1 = New myDelegate(AddressOf Subtraction)
    Subtraction1()
    Dim Addition1 As myDelegate
    Addition1 = New myDelegate(AddressOf Addition)
    Addition1()
    Dim Division1 As myDelegate
    Division1 = New myDelegate(AddressOf Division)
    Division1()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub Ask1()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter First Number")
    a = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Number")
    b = Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub Addition()
    Result = a + b
    Console.WriteLine("Added: " & Result)
End Sub
Sub Subtraction()
    Result = a - b
    Console.WriteLine("Subtracted: " & Result)
End Sub
Sub Multiply()
    result = a * b
    Console.WriteLine("Multiplied: " & Result)
End Sub
Sub Division()
    Console.WriteLine("Divided: " & a / b)
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? ...add this at the end of `Main`:

```
    Dim dMultiCast As myDelegate
    dMultiCast = [Delegate].Combine(New myDelegate(AddressOf Addition),
                                    New myDelegate(AddressOf Subtraction),
                                    New myDelegate(AddressOf Division),
                                    New myDelegate(AddressOf Multiply))
    dMultiCast.DynamicInvoke()

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```